# How to insert new values to Wordpress user Firstname and Surname Fields via DB

Tags: users

I have a custom sign up form in my Wordpress site which has confirmation email functionality for activating the account. For the confirmation step am keeping another DB table where am keeping the pending users info and when they are going with confirmation link then am copying the info from that table and adding to wp_users table. The issue is that i have First Name and Surname fields which info is being kept in another Wp table called wp_usermeta.

So my question is how i can insert the corresponding user firstname, surname when am adding the user to wp_users after confirmation like this

```
$checkUserID = $wpdb->get_results("SELECT * FROM pendingwpusers WHERE token = '".$gettokenval."'");
          $checkUserIDMain = $wpdb->query("SELECT * FROM store_users WHERE TrackNumber = '".$gettokenval."'"); 
          //$aaaa = mysql_num_rows($checkUserIDMain);
         //var_dump($checkUserIDMain);
            if($checkUserID && $checkUserIDMain == 0){    
                foreach ($checkUserID as $checkUser) {
                    //if(wp_mail($to, $subject, $message, $header)){}else{mail($to, $subject, $message, $header);}
                    $hashedpass = md5($checkUser->user_pass);
                    $wpdb->insert(
                        'store_users',
                        array(
                            'user_login' => $checkUser->user_login,
                            'user_pass' => $hashedpass,
                            'user_nicename' => $checkUser->user_nicename,
                            'user_email' => $checkUser->user_email,
                            'user_registered' => $checkUser->user_registered,
                            'display_name' => $checkUser->display_name,
                            'TrackNumber' => $checkUser->token
                        ),
                        array(
                                '%s',
                                '%s',
                                '%s',
                                '%s',
                                '%s',
                                '%s',
                                '%s',
                                '%s'
                        )
                    ); 
                }
          }
```

Comment: Any progress on the question/answer?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

If you have the ID of the user you can do this:

```
wp_update_user([
    'ID' => $userId, // this is the ID of the user you want to update.
    'first_name' => $firstName,
    'last_name' => $lastName,
]);
```

You can update / insert almost all fields with this function. Take a look at the documentation [here](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_update_user/)

Comment: Still works at 2020!

Comment: @eyal_katz I updated the link as well.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue (woocommerce test users) and wrote this shell script:

```
#!/bin/bash

# set for your local setup
DB=wordpress ; DBUSER=wordpress ; DBPASS=wordpress

INS_WPU="INSERT INTO wp_users (ID, user_login, user_pass, user_nicename, user_email, user_url, user_registered, user_activation_key, user_status, display_name) VALUES"
INS_WPM="INSERT INTO wp_usermeta (umeta_id, user_id, meta_key, meta_value) VALUES"
# password is 'testuser'
TESTUSERPASS='$P$BptzXm87Y8pxffjyy4Ur0ANs8uqW7J.'

function ins_test_user(){
    # 2 parameters : firstname, lastname
    NAM1="$1"
    NAM2="$2"

    # get the last unused wp_users ID
    SQL="select 1+max(ID) from wp_users into @wpuid;\n"
    # get the last unused wp_usermeta ID
    SQL="${SQL}select 1+max(umeta_id) from wp_usermeta into @wpmid;\n"

    # insert wp_users record
    SQL="${SQL}${INS_WPU} (@wpuid, '${NAM1}${NAM2}','${TESTUSERPASS}','${NAM1} ${NAM2}','${NAM1}.${NAM2}@example.org','http://${NAM1}.${NAM2}.example.com',now(),'',0,'test user ${CODE}');\n"

    # insert wp_usermeta records
    SQL="${SQL}${INS_WPM}(0+@wpmid,@wpuid,'billing_phone','');\n"
    SQL="${SQL}${INS_WPM}(1+@wpmid,@wpuid,'nickname','${NAM1} ${NAM2}');\n"
    SQL="${SQL}${INS_WPM}(2+@wpmid,@wpuid,'first_name','${NAM1}');\n"
    SQL="${SQL}${INS_WPM}(3+@wpmid,@wpuid,'last_name','${NAM2}');\n"
    SQL="${SQL}${INS_WPM}(4+@wpmid,@wpuid,'description','');\n"
    SQL="${SQL}${INS_WPM}(5+@wpmid,@wpuid,'rich_editing','true');\n"
    SQL="${SQL}${INS_WPM}(6+@wpmid,@wpuid,'syntax_highlighting','true');\n"
    SQL="${SQL}${INS_WPM}(7+@wpmid,@wpuid,'comment_shortcuts','false');\n"
    SQL="${SQL}${INS_WPM}(8+@wpmid,@wpuid,'admin_color','fresh');\n"
    SQL="${SQL}${INS_WPM}(9+@wpmid,@wpuid,'use_ssl','0');\n"
    SQL="${SQL}${INS_WPM}(10+@wpmid,@wpuid,'show_admin_bar_front','true');\n"
    SQL="${SQL}${INS_WPM}(11+@wpmid,@wpuid,'locale','');\n"
    SQL="${SQL}${INS_WPM}(12+@wpmid,@wpuid,'wp_capabilities','a:1:{s:8:\"customer\";b:1;}');\n"
    SQL="${SQL}${INS_WPM}(13+@wpmid,@wpuid,'wp_user_level','0');\n"
    SQL="${SQL}${INS_WPM}(14+@wpmid,@wpuid,'dismissed_wp_pointers','');\n"
    SQL="${SQL}${INS_WPM}(15+@wpmid,@wpuid,'billing_first_name','${NAM1}');\n"
    SQL="${SQL}${INS_WPM}(16+@wpmid,@wpuid,'billing_last_name','${NAM2}');\n"
    SQL="${SQL}${INS_WPM}(17+@wpmid,@wpuid,'billing_company','');\n"
    SQL="${SQL}${INS_WPM}(18+@wpmid,@wpuid,'billing_address_1','somewhere');\n"
    SQL="${SQL}${INS_WPM}(19+@wpmid,@wpuid,'billing_address_2','la la land');\n"
    SQL="${SQL}${INS_WPM}(20+@wpmid,@wpuid,'billing_city','X');\n"
    SQL="${SQL}${INS_WPM}(21+@wpmid,@wpuid,'billing_postcode','90210');\n"
    SQL="${SQL}${INS_WPM}(22+@wpmid,@wpuid,'billing_country','AF');\n"
    SQL="${SQL}${INS_WPM}(23+@wpmid,@wpuid,'billing_state','');\n"
    SQL="${SQL}${INS_WPM}(24+@wpmid,@wpuid,'billing_email','${NAM1}.${NAM2}@example.org');\n"
    SQL="${SQL}${INS_WPM}(25+@wpmid,@wpuid,'shipping_first_name','');\n"
    SQL="${SQL}${INS_WPM}(26+@wpmid,@wpuid,'shipping_last_name','');\n"
    SQL="${SQL}${INS_WPM}(27+@wpmid,@wpuid,'shipping_company','');\n"
    SQL="${SQL}${INS_WPM}(28+@wpmid,@wpuid,'shipping_address_1','');\n"
    SQL="${SQL}${INS_WPM}(29+@wpmid,@wpuid,'shipping_address_2','');\n"
    SQL="${SQL}${INS_WPM}(30+@wpmid,@wpuid,'shipping_city','');\n"
    SQL="${SQL}${INS_WPM}(31+@wpmid,@wpuid,'shipping_postcode','');\n"
    SQL="${SQL}${INS_WPM}(32+@wpmid,@wpuid,'shipping_country','');\n"
    SQL="${SQL}${INS_WPM}(33+@wpmid,@wpuid,'shipping_state','');\n"

    # commit after each user
    SQL="${SQL}commit;\n"

    echo -e "$SQL"
    }

{
echo "set autocommit=off;\n"

ins_test_user jane doe
ins_test_user joe bloggs
ins_test_user architeuthis dux
ins_test_user ftagn fnord
ins_test_user pete brick
ins_test_user kaiser soze

echo "set autocommit=on;\n"
} | mysql -D $DB -u $DBUSER --password="$DBPASS"
```